# How to let multiple figures in right position

Tags: floats

I inserted four figures, one by one. And then I added one paragraph of content. But I find the paragraph between the figures - First two figures, then one paragraph, and then one figure. How can I keep the position of the figures in the right place?

[image]

My code is like this:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{subfigure}    
\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}[hbtp]    
\centering    
\includegraphics[scale=1]{C:/Users/tr/Pictures/Experiment1.png}    
\caption{First Time Experiment}    
\end{figure}    
\begin{figure}[hbtp]    
\centering    
\includegraphics[scale=1]{C:/Users/tr/Pictures/Experiment2.png}    
\caption{Second Time Experiment}    
\end{figure}    
\begin{figure}[hbtp]    
\centering    
\includegraphics[scale=1]{C:/Users/tr/Pictures/Experiment3.png}    
\caption{Third Time Experiment}    
\end{figure}    
\begin{figure}[hbtp]    
\centering    
\includegraphics[scale=1]{C:/Users/tr/Pictures/Experiment4.png}    
\caption{Fourth Time Experiment}    
\end{figure}

As the figures do, the researcher observes the following principles: ajie%
As the figures do, the researcher observes the following principles: ajie%
As the figures do, the researcher observes the following principles: ajie%
As the figures do, the researcher observes the following principles: ajie\\%\
\end{document}
```

Comment: It did not say that clear how to avoid the "content" being in the position that is between the figures.

Comment: On a different note, I'd suggest that you discontinue using the now obsolete `subfigure` package and use `captions` & `subcaptions` packages instead for customizing the figure & sub-figure captions, respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick fix:  Use `h!` option for 4th (and 5th, 6th, ...) `figure` environment.

Comment: This does not work. The txt content is still located in the position that is between the figures

Comment: @YulongZhang: The mentioned duplicate lists an option using the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) and using the `[H]` option. Did you read the linked post?

Comment: Using `[h!]` routinely is very likely to produce severely under-full pages.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me if the four graphs should be stacked vertically, or if two will fit next to each other; the sketch you posted seems to suggest the latter.

If two figures can fit side-by-side, I suggest you use a *single* `figure` environment, with four `minipage` environments sized to contain one graph and one `\caption` instruction. Note that it's not necessary to load the `subfigure` package (which, anyway, has long been deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}   % don't use "demo" option in real document   
\begin{document}    

\begin{figure}  
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth} 
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{C:/Users/tr/Pictures/Experiment1.png}    
\caption{First Time Experiment}    
\end{minipage}    
\hspace{\fill}  %% no blank line before of after this instruction
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth} 
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{C:/Users/tr/Pictures/Experiment2.png}    
\caption{Second Time Experiment}    
\end{minipage}    

\vspace{0.75cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth} 
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{C:/Users/tr/Pictures/Experiment3.png}    
\caption{Third Time Experiment}    
\end{minipage}    
\hspace{\fill} %% no blank line before of after this instruction
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth} 
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{C:/Users/tr/Pictures/Experiment4.png}    
\caption{Fourth Time Experiment}    
\end{minipage}    

\end{figure}

As the figures do, the researcher observes the following principles: ajie%
As the figures do, the researcher observes the following principles: ajie%
As the figures do, the researcher observes the following principles: ajie%
As the figures do, the researcher observes the following principles: ajie\\%\

\end{document}
```

If, on the other hand, the four graphs need to be stacked vertically, and if the four graphs and their captions can all fit on a single page, I still suggest you use a single `figure` environment. Note that LaTeX will almost certainly place such a tall `figure` on a page by itself.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}    
\begin{document}    

\begin{figure}   
\centering

\includegraphics[scale = 1]{C:/Users/tr/Pictures/Experiment1.png}    
\caption{First Time Experiment}    

\vspace{0.75cm}
\includegraphics[scale = 1]{C:/Users/tr/Pictures/Experiment2.png}    
\caption{Second Time Experiment}    

\vspace{0.75cm}
\includegraphics[scale = 1]{C:/Users/tr/Pictures/Experiment3.png}    
\caption{Third Time Experiment}    

\vspace{0.75cm}
\includegraphics[scale = 1]{C:/Users/tr/Pictures/Experiment4.png}    
\caption{Fourth Time Experiment}    

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```