# How to include 3 vertically aligned subfigures, while making them appear as 3 separate "Main" (and not sub-) figures?

Tags: floats, captions, positioning, subfloats, subcaption

I want to place 3 figures on top of each other and I figured out a way to do that using `subcaption` package. But, they appear as sub-figures and not the "main" figures. I think it's because of the package I used, but I found it very hard to place 3 figures on top of each other, if I just used 3 separate `\begin{figure}`, so I used this. Can I still use `subcaption` and turn them into "main" figures. I want to use `subcaption` because I was able to do what I needed, instantly, so I really like how simple it is. Also, there are other problems:

1. The "main" figure title shows up and I can't hide it.
2. This title and 3 figures are not properly placed at centre.
3. Also, the titles of 3 figures are pushed right! I want everything in centre and aligned nicely.
4. The figure title numbers are like this - `(a), (b)` and I want them to be like `1.: Title`, like how the main title shows, but in bold font.

Is it possible to do? Here's what I've used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}     
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.56\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{}
    \caption{First SUB-FLOAT}
    \label{fig:demo1}
  \end{subfigure}
   \begin{subfigure}{0.56\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{}
    \caption{Second SUB-FLOAT}
    \label{fig:demo2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.56\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{}
    \caption{Third SUB-FLOAT}
    \label{fig:demo3}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Demo}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

Please help!

Comment: you just need three `\caption` commands, not subfigure at all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, but doing so would mean that I loose the control over `figure` environment caption, if I need to revert back to a more standard `figure`-`subfigure` setup. My answer given below sheds more light on how it allows me to revert back to a standard setup, if need be, by simply modifying the `\captionsetup` variables for both the `figure` & `subfigure` environments.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [last code shown here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247858/78565) to achieve what you want without using `subcaption` package at all.

But, since your question is specifically regarding how you can achieve your result using `subcaption` package, here's a solution to your problems.

Now, there are several "essential" bits missing from your code. So, let's look at them one by one:

1. You include only the `subcaption` package. It's always better to
   load both the `caption` and the `subcaption` packages together, in
   that order. As, `caption` package will allow you to customise all
   sorts of float captions with great flexibility.
2. Instead of using `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}`, you may use the
       `mwe` package to display example images. The black boxes are
       replaced by better looking grey-scale images.
3. The horizontal alignment of your figures & captions goes off-centre,
       because you've used `\centering` only once for the outer `figure`
       environment. For proper alignment, you must repeat `\centering` in
       all 3 `subfigure` environments as well.
4. Also, it's better to use
       `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}` after
       `\begin{subfigure}{0.56\textwidth}` than using
       `\includegraphics{example-image-a}`; as it will help achieving the
       proper scaling of your images.
5. Another problem with your code, and this is a big one, is that you
       are missing the **mandatory empty-line** between two `subfigure`
       environments. [See this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Subfloats) for further explanation. You don't see
       any difference due to the image scaling you have chosen. As an
       experiment, change `\begin{subfigure}{0.56\textwidth}` to
       `\begin{subfigure}{0.2\textwidth}` and see what happens. If you want
       3 figures aligned vertically, one top of another, you have to
       maintain the **all essential empty-line** between two sub-figures.

To meet your requirements, I had to add a few lines of code as follows:

```
%%%%%% begin: caption/subcaption setup %%%%%%
\renewcommand\thefigure{Main-\arabic{figure}}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{simplab}{Figure~#2}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{nocap}{}
\DeclareCaptionSubType*{figure}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\arabic{subfigure}}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{%
            font={normalsize},
            labelfont={bf},
            labelformat=simplab,
            labelsep=colon,
            singlelinecheck=true,
            position=bottom
            }%
%%%%%% end: caption/subcaption setup %%%%%%
```

- The first definition, `\renewcommand\thefigure{Main-\arabic{figure}}`
  is not absolutely essential in this case, but it helps to
  differentiate the reference to the main figure (if needed in future)
  from your pseudo-subfigures, since you need them to look exactly like
  the main figures!
- `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{}{}` & `\DeclareCaptionFormat{}{}` are
  from the `caption` package; whereas, `\captionsetup[subfigure]{}` &
  `\DeclareCaptionSubType*{figure}` are from the `subcaption` package.
  For further information, please look at the package documentation of
  [`caption`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf) & [`subcaption`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf).
- `\DeclareCaptionFormat{nocap}{}` defines a special empty-caption
  format for main figure environments.
- `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{simplab}{Figure~#2}` defines how the
  figure labels are typeset.
- `\DeclareCaptionSubType*{figure}` allows us to manually redefine
  subfigure caption format using `\renewcommand` and
  `\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\arabic{subfigure}}` redefines
  `\thesubfigure`  counter to print arabic numbers.
- `\captionsetup[subfigure]{}` sets up the subfigure caption font size
  to `normalsize`, label to `\bfseries`, label separator to `colon` and
  label format to `simplab` which is defined earlier using
  `\DeclareCaptionFormat{}{}`.
- Moreover, to hide the main figure caption, we use `format=nocap` in
  the `\captionsetup{}` of the main figure caption. The `nocap` format
  was defined earlier using `\DeclareCaptionFormat{}{}`.

There's actually no real need to do this, because hiding the main caption is as simple as commenting out the `\caption{}` line using `%`. However, if the user still wants to refer to these 3 figures collectively, the main caption will have to be present and active (i.e. uncommented). Whichever is the case, I find it most practical just to define a custom empty-caption format and switch between the normal & the empty formats as needed, while retaining the entire caption line as it is, than to completely remove it. If, in future, the user decides to print the main caption, it is already there at the switch of a label format! Isn't that convenient? :) .. *See it yourself by deleting* `format=nocap` *from the* `\captionsetup{}` *of the main figure caption!*

I have also included the reference to main caption inside subcaptions, just to show that even though the main caption doesn't show up in the output PDF, it is very much valid/ active and its label can be referenced easily.

**Here's the MWE code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mwe}    % for example figures!
%%%%%% begin: caption/subcaption setup %%%%%%
\renewcommand\thefigure{Main-\arabic{figure}}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{simplab}{Figure~#2}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{nocap}{}
\DeclareCaptionSubType*{figure}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\arabic{subfigure}}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{%
            font={normalsize},
            labelfont={bf},
            labelformat=simplab,
            labelsep=colon,
            singlelinecheck=true,
            position=bottom
            }%
%%%%%% end: caption/subcaption setup %%%%%%         
\pagestyle{empty}           
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
 \centering
 \vspace*{5pt}%
 \hspace*{\fill}% 
  \begin{subfigure}{0.56\textwidth}     % start subfigure 1
    %\belowcaptionskip=8pt
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \captionsetup{skip=12pt}%
    \caption{First SUB-FLOAT (\ref{fig:demoMain})}
    \label{fig:demo1}
  \end{subfigure}%          % end subfigure 1
  \hspace*{\fill}%          % empty line absolutely necessary!

  \vspace*{8pt}%  

  \hspace*{\fill}%  
   \begin{subfigure}{0.56\textwidth}        % start subfigure 2
    %\belowcaptionskip=8pt
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
    \captionsetup{skip=12pt}%
    \caption{Second SUB-FLOAT (\ref{fig:demoMain})}
    \label{fig:demo2}
  \end{subfigure}%          % end subfigure 2  
  \hspace*{\fill}%          % empty line absolutely necessary!

  \vspace*{8pt}%

  \hspace*{\fill}%  
  \begin{subfigure}{0.56\textwidth}     % start subfigure 3
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}%
    \captionsetup{skip=12pt}%
    \caption{Third SUB-FLOAT (\ref{fig:demoMain})}
    \label{fig:demo3}
  \end{subfigure}%              % end subfigure 3
  \hspace*{\fill}%
  \captionsetup{skip=8pt, format=nocap}% % required to hide the figure (main) lable!
  \caption{This is a main Float}
  \label{fig:demoMain}
\end{figure}
\cleardoublepage
\end{document}
```

**Here's how the output PDF looks:**

[image]

Hope you find it useful! :)

Answer (score 1):

The `floatrow` package can do rows of figures, as well as rows of subfigures, quite easily, with its `\ffigbox{figure}{caption}` and `\tabbox{table}{caption}` commands and `floatrow` and `subfloatrow` environments. See more details inthe documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption, floatrow}
\captionsetup{labelfont={sc, small}}
\DeclareFloatVCode{myrowsep}{\vskip 4ex}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
  \floatsetup{justification =centering, rowpostcode=myrowsep}
  \begin{floatrow}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.56\textwidth]{\figa}}{\caption{First SUB-FLOAT}\label{fig:demo1}}
  \end{floatrow}
  \begin{floatrow}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.66\textwidth]{\figb}}{\caption{Second SUB-FLOAT}\label{fig:demo2}}
  \end{floatrow}
  \begin{floatrow}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.56\textwidth]{\figc}}{\caption{Second SUB-FLOAT}\label{fig:demo3}}
  \end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}%
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
% figure vertical allignment 
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{images/figure01.png}
        %\caption{Choose any caption if you want to add }}
    \end{subfigure}%
    
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{images/figure02.png}
        %\caption{Add second caption if you like}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{images/figure03.png}
        %\caption{Add third caption if you like}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{this is the overall caption}
\end{figure}
```